# Capture frame from streaming in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm looking around find a method for streaming from my RPi camera board with 20-25 fps and capture frame by an OpenCV program in my desktop. I find this [tut](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-stream-video-from-your-raspicam-to-your-nexus-7-tablet-using-vlc) for streaming the quality and fps are quite good but I don't know how to capture frame by OpenCV.

I also tried mjpeg but fps is low, I don't know why  and I don't think write continuously in sd card is recommended.

Comment: You can try mjpeg streamer on RPi to stream video to web and use [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) to capture stream , works fine for me.

Comment: @Haris, could you, please give me example of your approach?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a script either in Python or other languages in which you are comfortable with. Here's is the link for the tutorials using OpenCV with python - http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video.